Are there any organizations calling for restoration of Americas to the native american peoples?
The criticism of Israel on US university campuses is often ideologically grounded in anti-colonialist discourse. E.g., Columbia University Palestinian-American professor Rashid Khalidi is one of the proponents of such a view:

It was a national project. Herzl was a national founder of a national movement whose means were explicitly settler-colonial. There is historical precedent. We have the United States of America. We have Canada. We have Australia. We have New Zealand. These are all settler-colonial projects that have become national projects.

However, Israel is a somewhat of a "soft target" - it is sensitive to criticism, relatively recent, has lots of enemies in the Middle East, and its criticism is always bound to find broad support due to the historical animosity towards Jews in western world. I wonder, if any organizations adopt more ambitious goals - like liberating the US from white colonizers ("from Pacific to Atlantic..." or something like that°. Or perhaps those, among Israel's opponents, who see liberation of Palestine as only the first step in a larger struggle?

Several South American countries see themselves as indigenous states now. They've happened to preserve most of the native american lineage.

In general I would not set the bar that high with "liberating America". What about more privileges like increased territory, more self-determination, more financial compensation? That list could be almost endless but still falling considerably short of extermination of white populations.

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/1813/26455.

VTC - Duplicate as @RickSmith pointed out - the answer there answers this Q too. Also, because this question can be construed as "push" Q (hints of Israeli fundamentalist propaganda - "colonisation is nothing new, most of the west have done it before, and it was all ok when white Christians where doing it, but Israel is targeted only because jews are doing it now" - the reality is that colonisation or harsh colonial policies are no longer politically accepted by the world today and freedom movement for political rights and dignity receive a lot of serious support from all democracies.)

One could read this question and get the impression that Rashid Khalidi advocates for the expulsion of non-Palestinian people from Israel and Palestine or something, since the first paragraph quotes him and the question talks about people who might support "the restoration of the Americas to the Native American peoples" or "liberating the US from white colonizers." In reality, Khalidi has been pretty consistent in saying that he views both Israelis and Palestinians as having a right to self-determination, but views the Palestinian rights as having been neglected.

So he wouldn't be an example of someone who would want to "give all of Israel back to the Palestinians" in any meaningful sense, although he has said that the injustices should be "remediated." Notably, and relevant to this question, he also strongly criticized Hamas's attacks on October 7 by making an analogy to the USA, saying that no one could justify firing a rocket at his apartment building because he lived on land that had been taken from Indigenous Americans, and that one either supports international human rights or one doesn't.

Although in the interests of fairness, I do feel compelled to point out the misleading nature of Khalidi's statement in that article that "once upon a time, there was a Jewish minority in parts of Palestine." That statement, while an accurate description of the situation during a fairly long historical period, might give the inaccurate impression that there was never a sizeable Jewish majority in most of what is now Palestine and Israel, when there in fact was up until somewhat under 2000 years ago.

For what it's worth, in the USA, I'm aware of several "land back" movements urging the return of certain territories to Native tribes, but so far as I am aware, most of them focus on federal lands or voluntary donations, and none that I am aware of with any substantial support advocates for the legal ownership of all land by some tribe or the expulsion of all non-tribal members from the USA, to say nothing of all non-Indigenous people from the Americas. Of course, fewer pro-Palestinian organizations than some think want to destroy the Israeli government, let alone expel all Israelis, so....

@Obie2.0 the question is not about Khalidi, but about the consistency of anti-colonial ideology as a justification for anti-Israeli protests: is it consistently applied or are Israel/Jews singled out? Clearly, Palestinians are not the only ones denied self-determination - whether in all of Palestine or a part of it. I agree that with pro-Palestinian protesters it is often unclear whom they defend, when they speak of "Palestine" or "Gaza" - Palestinian people? Hamas? What about the Palestinian refugees outside of Palestine?

@alamar Palestinians usually talk in terms of a just solution vs. acceptable solution. The former means liberating "all of the Palestine", the latter - accepting what they can have now (a state alongside Israel), without ever renouncing their eventual goal of liberating the whole. Also, I am not sure what you mean by more self-determination - you either have it or not, there is no middle ground.

@Morisco, maybe Palestine is not singled out, as south Africa was also in a similar situation. Liberating India from British Colonialism is another example which was strongly persuaded by, say, Sayyed Jamal AsadAbadi who was then after somewhat followed by Gandhi, and Asad Abadi was trying to unite people in the Middle East against the British empire and European Colonialism.

@owari to my knowledge, South Africa wasn't about national independence or expulsion of colonizers, do I don't see the parallels. I also do not see what India or many other past examples of rich colonial history have to do with the modern examplesin the Q.

sorry my comment was only a comment on a comment of yours and not about your Q, and I have no clue right about your question other than perhaps seeing people here and there trying to unite against imperialism, somewhat like imperialism having occupied their countries, the governments serving a system instead of their own people. This can be liberating US and other western or eastern countries, but doesn't seem like an answer to your Q yet, and have no reference for it either.

The funny thing with this question is seems to imply "If the US and Canada don't acknowledge the claims of natives dating back to 200 years then why make a fuss over claims of Palestinians dating back 80 years?  They lost their land too, so sad!" Meanwhile, no doubt, Israeli claims to the land dating back to 2000 years exist in a different universe where they are absolute and totally different from the regrettable-but-such-is-life losses experienced by American natives and Palestinians.  "Palestine was never a nation" is all the explanation ever needed, or given, here.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica beautiful deconstruction of your own interpretation of this Q. Btw, my views on the reality of the Palestinians and their right to the state are well documented in this community - they are quite different from the stereotypes that you cite here (or more precisely the stereotype about stereotypes.)
